# Can I restore a deleted calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, calendar

I accidentally deleted an entire Google Calendar. Is there any method that allows me to restore it except using the method [described by Google Support](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/7143502/i-accidentally-deleted-an-entire-calendar-how-can-i-restore-it-it-hasn-t-ever-been-backed-up?hl=en) (i.e. [using Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/list))? Because [it is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76315915/1469208) in my case.

Things that I have managed to check:

- The calendar [hasn't ever been backed up](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings/export)
- The calendar isn't (wasn't) shared with anyone
- I have stopped syncing it on my mobile and turned off all devices' Internet access, but the calendar was deleted from there as well

[Google Support says](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37188?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cdelete-a-calendar-cant-be-undone):

> Delete a calendar (can't be undone)

So I am pretty much sure, I am done here. But, just want to double-check with you before I start tossing dirt over this.